# Excel deletes content after copying a column

Tags: excel, winforms, office-interop

This looks really weird to me:
I simply copy a column, it appears for 0.5 seconds, then the contents disappear. It is entirely reproducible (with the same file).
`ws` is a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet` (V15), with Office 365.
The workbook is an .xlsx file, there cannot be any macros.

[image: animation]

I can even stop after `.Insert`, and then perform the command inside Excel:

```
Columns(3).Copy(Columns(4))
```

This works and persists. When I continue in Visual Studio, it again copies and then deletes the content.
What can be going on here?

(I cannot upload the original file)
This is a .net framework 4.8 winforms app.

Comment: It is not VBA for sure, what language are you using?

Comment: Where is the vba code to support your VBA tag?

Comment: Fine, I delete the VBA tag.

Comment: Does the source column have a conditional format applied that may be obscuring the newly inserted column?  While debugging, go to the worksheet and click on an inserted cell and observe Excel's formula bar to see if the cell has a value ,but it is just not visible as formatted.

Comment: What happens if you use a different Excel file? In other words, does the code result in the same behavior in a different Excel file or is the problem only with one particular Excel file? Please provide a [mre] so we can test the code.

Comment: @TnTinMn Two points on that: a) the column is created only right there with the .Insert you see in the code, b) as stated, when I run the .Copy command in Excel/VBA, the contents do not disappear, but (also @JohnG) I can do more tests with other columns and files from the same customer, but only on monday (it seems to occur in all files from this customer)

Comment: If the problem ONLY happens with a “particular customers” Excel file… then I would look closer at those Excel files. In my small tests, the posted code worked as expected without errors. Without some code that reproduces the problem you describe… it would be pure speculation. It appears clear IMO that something is different in that particular customers Excel files. In other words, quit wasting time looking at the code (that works) and instead look at the Excel file.